# Is it possible to mix C and Swift?

Tags: c, swift

I've studied the basics of Swift and some C. How could I combine C and Swift in one project? Could I ignore Objective-C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is very much possible to mix Swift and C.  In fact it's pretty easy.  For example, if you type `import Darwin` into a playground, you will find all sorts of C functions:

```
import Darwin

let i = atoi("42")
let path = String.fromCString(getenv("PATH"))

let voidptr = malloc(10 * UInt(sizeof(Int)))
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(voidptr)
for i in 0..<10 {
    ptr[i] = i
}
let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: 10)
reduce(buffer, 0, +) // sum(1 to 10) = 45
free(ptr)
```

There are various convenience conversions, for example in the above code, "42" was automatically converted to a C-style string to be passed into `atoi`.  Similarly, if you declare `var i: Int = 0`, you can pass that into a C API that takes a C pointer-to-int as `f(&i)`, and arrays are similarly auto-converted to pointers when you pass them in.

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11) on the Apple website for more info on how you can interact with C from Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely interface directly with C code. [This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11) has a lot more details on how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is designed for seamless compatibility with Objective-C. It means we can use Swift API in Objective-C and vice versa.

Using swift can surely interact with the library purely written in C. And it is the best way to use the same libraries across different mobile platforms, because both Android and iOS supports pure C. However, you need not learn Objective-C because we can develop applications using only swift.

Note from Apples documentation: You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.